# AWS Javascript SDK: upload object with metadata

Tags: aws-sdk-js

Tye AWS.S3.ManagedUpload object allows you to upload an object specifying "tags", but I don't see any documentation for specifying meta data on an uploaded object. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketTagging-property)

Comment: @AlexanderVitanov thanks for that link, but that adds tags to a bucket. I am looking for a way to add metadata to an uploaded object using AWS.S3.ManagedUpload, either when the object is uploaded or afterwards.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try with the following:

```
const params = {
  Metadata: {
    'my-key': 'some-value',
  },
}
s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
});
```

Note that the SDK will add the prefix **x-amz-meta-**

Comment: That works thank you.  However, when I use the x-amz-meta prefix as shown and look at the metadata in the AWS console, that prefix is doubled in the Key. Using your example above, the key shows as x-amz-meta-x-amz-meta-my-key. I can see in the browser network debugger that it is that way in the request headers also.  Perhaps the SDK is adding that prefix for me, so I don't need to in the Metadata hash? Testing without that prefix in the hash, it still shows up in the AWS console with that prefix - once, not twice.

Comment: You are right - no need to add it as the sdk does it for you. Nevertheless, it must be present.

Comment: x-amz-meta- does not need to be present in your params Metadata definition.

Adding only 'my-key': 'some-value' to the definition will result in a metatdata key of x-amz-meta-my-key being present on your object in s3.

Comment: There's no need specifying `x-amz-meta-` prefix manually, as SDK will add it automatically. Keep in mind though that keys MUST BE LOWERCASE (as AWS will store them lowercase anyways https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata) also ideally those should be ascii characters. If  you have non-ascii chars you may get missing metadata (but keep your eye on ` x-amz-missing-meta` header in this case).

Comment: While this code allows me to set a user defined meta header "Content-Type" in S3, it does not change the system defined meta header.

Is there a function call in Javascript AWS version 3 that will let me change the System defined "Content-Type" meta header and set a System defined "Content-Disposition" meta header?

Comment: @DavieOverman in the available params settings for S3 uploads there are ContentType and ContentDisposition that will set the "System Defined" metas: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html